# Can I approximate the inverse by inverse of the approximation?

Tags: taylor-expansion, inverse, approximation

I haven't seen this done before, but I'm sure it's possible.

Suppose $f$ is analytic on $[x_1,x_2]$ with range $[y_1,y_2],$ then its Taylor series converges on this interval and it is branch-invertible. Let $f_2$ be the second-order Taylor approximation of the $n$th-order Taylor approximation $f_n,$ such that $f_2(x) = ax^2 + bx + c.$

The branch-inverses of $ax^2 + bx + c$ are the two functions $\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 + 4ax - 4ac}}{2a}.$

Now, the inverse function of $f,$ $f^{-1},$ is also bounded on the domain $[y_1,y_2].$

My more general question is: as $n \rightarrow \infty,$ does $f_n^{-1}$ converge to $f^{-1}$? And thus can I claim that $\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 + 4ax - 4ac}}{2a}$ is a reasonable local approximation (heuristically speaking) of $f^{-1},$ such that for some upper bound M where $|f^{-1}(x)| < M,$ $|f_2^{-1}|<M$ over some subset of $[y_1,y_2]$?

If you feel inclined to adjust this approach to "suppose $f$ is monotone..." I am open to that as well.

Comment: was curious so tested it on the function $ \ln(1+x^2)\approx x^2 $ using a calculator.
the original inverse is $ y=\sqrt{e^y-1}$ while the approximated inverse is $y=\sqrt{x} $
for x=$\frac{1}{3} $ we get $f_{inverse}(\frac{1}{3})=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\approx 0.62 $ while $f_{approxinverse}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}} \approx 0.577 $ 
for $ x=0.1 $ we get that $ f_{inverse}=\sqrt{e^\frac{1}{10}-1}\approx 0.324 $ while $ f_{inverseapprox}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{10}} \approx 0.316 $

Comment: "...and it is invertible": I'm not sure what you mean by this. Taken at face value, it seems false.

Comment: Branch invertible, no essential singularities where the set of branches is dense over a compact set and no weierstrass functions.

Comment: Clearly "some subset of $[y_1,y_2]$" cannot always be just $[y_1,y_2]$ itself. It seems "obvious" that if you restrict to a small enough subset of $[y_1,y_2]$ you will have not only a suitable invertible piece of the Taylor function, but the error will be bounded by some finite $M$. But the thing about Taylor series is that we're able to use information from the problem statement to compute a useful value of $M$. What does that procedure look like for the inverse function?

Comment: If you're talking about a compact set, then the inverse has to be bounded. An analytic function is certainly continuous, and over a compact set, any continuous function attains its min and max. As I said, you're free to talk about monotone restrictions if that's all you can come up with.